# Open more than one Modal on same page in Materialize

Tags: modal-dialog, materialize

I have a page where I plan on having multiple modals that can be opened. The first one works fine, I link to it in several places on the page. When I added the second one though upon clicking it all I get it a darkened screen. The modal doesn't show up.

I read through everything I could find both here and on materialize website. Tried a few things like adding multiple triggers to init.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
$('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
  });

$(document).ready(function(){
    // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal     ID that wants to be triggered
   $('.modal-trigger1').leanModal();
  });
```

Nut that didn't do anything. Tried calling it as a js function under onclick instead of through the href tag and class, but its the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the modals just below the **calling button**, it may work. I've gone through it a lot of times. So go through it once, if it still create a problem please let me know. And please post the modal code also.

Answer (score 0):

> When I added the second one though upon clicking it all I get it a darkened screen

It's mean that it could not get the id of second modal.